# 1-D into 2-D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

A program in c++ that accept an integer array and its size as arguments and assign the elements into a 2-D array of integers.
for ex:
if the array is 1,2,3
The resultant 2-D array is given by

1 2 3
1 2 0
1 0 0

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: can you please give me the logic

Comment: Did you even *bother* to try to do this yourself?

Comment: Requests for concrete solutions to homework problems are not questions. Voted to close. (While here you added a comment requesting only the logic, in the existing answer you explicitly requrested the code after presented with the logic).

Answer (score 3):

> can you please give me the logic

The logic is very simple. Let n be the size of the 1D array.

```
create a 2d array of size n x n
for y in [0, n)
    copy elements [0, n-y) from the 1D array to line y
    set elements [n-y, n) to 0 in line y
```

...and that's basically it, where `[begin, end)` denotes a half open range.

Comment: @anurag: Where exactly are you having trouble transforming my pseudo code into C++? It's fairly straightforward.